# Execute a command after successful EasyMotion's motion

Tags: vimrc, plugin-easymotion

I've [EasyMotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) plugin installed.

I want to execute a command (G just for example) after a motion (note: the motion requires an user's input) is completed. In my `~/.vimrc` I've tried to do it by joining the commands with `<Bar>` but after execution it shows `EasyMotion: No matches` and moves cursor to EOF.

```
map  <Leader>f <Plug>(easymotion-bd-f) <Bar> G
```

Comment: The `G` is probably responsible for going EOF. I understand that you would like that it is executed only if the `easymotion-bd-f` is not escaped. Do I have the correct understanding?

Comment: You are right. EOF is expected in my example but the motion wasn't executed at all in my case. May be it's an issue on EasyMotion's side. I'm new to Vim and I can't tell.